# Caliburn.Micro WindowManager and Window constructor parameter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

It looks like Caliburn.Micro's WindowManager have problem with WPF Windows, that have constructor parameter although that parameter's type is registered in Caliburn.Micro IoC. Is there better way to put that needed parameter into Window except using stinking service locator `IoC.Get(Of T)` in constructor?

```
Namespace Views
  Class MainWindowView
    Private _eventAggregator As IEventAggregator
    Public Sub New(eventAggregator As IEventAggregator)
      _eventAggregator = eventAggregator
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace  

Sub ShowMainWindowView()
  'Everything is correctly registered in Ioc...
  Dim windowManager As New WindowManager
  Dim viewModel As New MainWindowViewModel
  windowManager.ShowDialog(viewModel)
  'Exception is thrown about absence of parameterless constructor of MainWindowView
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem? Are you getting an error?  What does your code look like?  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks the wrong way around. Your view model should be interacting with the window manager not the view.

Comment: Sure it is, that ShowMainWindowView method can be anywhere. In my case it is in command method of view model.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what the question is? Put the window manager as a parameter to the view model constructor as you've done with the `MainWindowView` and the event aggregator?.

Comment: The problem is that WindowManager can not work with Window, that have parameter(s) in constructor. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this problem again in new, clear project and it works - it is only needed to have type of view (Window) registered in IoC container and WindowManager automatically injects required dependencies in view's constructor.